# how to get spyder to display function arguments

Tags: spyder

I have just set up Spyder 3.3.1 and it is not displaying a list of function arguments like other editors do.

For example

If I type

```
import math
math.
```

I would like a list of all of the functions that I could use, such as sin, tanh and sqrt, to be displayed after "math." so that I can scroll through and select the math function I want to use.

I have tried cmd+I and the advice from other posts but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for any help and advice.

Chris

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) `Cmd+I` is to get help. `Tab` is what you need for code completion.

Comment: Hi Carlos. Thanks for your response. that Tab seems to work for selecting the variable but not for functions of the variable. For example, if I type m and then press Tab it will show me a drop down list of objects like my_list, math, my_vars and I can choose which one I want to use. But if I type math. then press Tab it doesn't do anything. If I type my_list. then press Tab it auto completes it to my_list.append without giving me any choice of how I would like it to complete it. Have you ever had an issue like this?

Comment: I don't understand why `math.` is not working for you, sorry. That's very simple to get completions for.